# Unable to resolve Imported module

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

I have the following directory structure in my react-native project.

```
  project
    |-- src
    |    |-- components 
    |    |    |-- ComponentA
    |    |    |    |-- ComponentA.js
    |    |    |-- ComponentB
    |    |    |    |-- ComponentB.js
    |--App.js
    |--Package.json
```

In ComponentA.js I am trying to import ComponentB like so:

```
import ComponentB from '../../ComponentB'
```

But this gives me an error (500):

> Unable to resolve module ../../ComponentB ..

Then I tried:

```
  import ComponentB from './src/components/ComponentB'
```

But still the same error.

I also tried:

```
 import ComponentB from './src/components/ComponentB/ComponentB.js'
```

But also no solution.

Comment: `'../ComponentB/ComponentB'`?

Comment: No that didn't work either

Comment: Are you exporting default or just exporting?

Comment: What do you export from `ComponentB`?

Comment: it should be `import ComponentB from '../componentB/ComponentB`

Comment: Both ComponentA and Component B are `export default ComponentA` extends Component. and `export default ComponentB` extends Component

Comment: paths are relative to which file you are importing

Answer (score 0):

If you are default exporting, then
`import ComponentB from '../ComponentB/ComponentB'`
If you just want to use `'../ComponentB'` you need to name your file inside `componentB` folder `index.js`

Because `'./'` is the same level so you are in the same level as ComponentA, and you tried to reach like this: `ComponentA/src/....`
when you tried `'../../'` you reached 2 levels higher, so the path was: `'src/ComponentB`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`import ComponentB from '../ComponentB/ComponentB`'

This will work because you are trying to access component but you were not reaching to component and when you will use above code then it will go out of your current directory and then again to components directory and then to folder `ComponentB` and then file name named `ComponentB`. So now you will be able to access your `ComponentB` from file `ComponentB`.